# where did the other/ come from?

Tags: javascript

why some thing like this

```
url="http:/"+"www.pathname.com"+"/"+"anotherString";
```

turns into `http://www.pathname.com/anotherString`.
Notice the `//` after the http:.

Comment: Does no work for me, I get `http:/www.pathname.com/anotherString`. No other `/`.

Comment: Cannot reproduce. Are you assigning to `window.location` instead of a generic variable `url`?

Comment: I think you wrote \  instead of /

Comment: yeah i was assigning window.location

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An interesting anecdote: Nokia older phones write http:/ instead of http://.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure what you mean exactly, but if it is in the URL bar of the web-browser, then it is just correcting you. you are meant to have the two forward slashes their. Its just the way you are meant to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Its just the way urls are designed, and the way browsers interpret them. For more details see this blog post

**[Double slash in Web addresses 'a bit of a mistake'](http://blogs.zdnet.com/igeneration/?p=3090)** and

[**Berners-Lee 'sorry' for slashes**](http://news.bbc.co.uk/2/hi/technology/8306631.stm)

Comment: I love in the first link, they say the evolution of web3 like there is some function difference to way the WWW works.

Answer (score 0):

As a string in your file, it does not add an extra `/` to it, but if you type that string into the browser address bar, the browser will automatically add the additional `/` to the URL to make it valid. I do believe it will do this for images and other links on the page to make them valid.